# Read Shapefiles into Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, type-conversion, shapefile

I have a shapefile that I would like to convert into dataframe in Python 3.7. I have tried the following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import shapefile
sf_path = r'data/shapefile'
sf = shapefile.Reader(sf_path, encoding = 'Shift-JIS')

fields = [x[0] for x in sf.fields][1:]
records = sf.records()
shps = [s.points for s in sf.shapes()]

sf_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = fields, data = records)
```

But I got this error message saying

```
TypeError: Expected list, got _Record
```

So how should I convert the list to _Record or is there a way around it? I have tried GeoPandas too, but had some trouble installing it. Thanks!

Comment: What type is `shapefile`? It is said that the required input is a `list`

Comment: @Yusufsn In my editor, it shows that "records" is a list of "_Record". A shapefile is a geometric file with both the longitude/latitude and some other information.

Comment: Could you please provide the input sample from your `shapefile`?

Answer (score 3):

```
def read_shapefile(sf_shape):
    """
    Read a shapefile into a Pandas dataframe with a 'coords' 
    column holding the geometry information. This uses the pyshp
    package
    """

    fields = [x[0] for x in sf_shape.fields][1:]
    records = [y[:] for y in sf_shape.records()]
    #records = sf_shape.records()
    shps = [s.points for s in sf_shape.shapes()]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=fields, data=records)
    df = df.assign(coords=shps)
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is because the *.shp* file has a kind of key field in each record and when converting to dataframe, a list is expected and only that field is found, test changing:

```
  records = [y[:] for y in sf.records()]
```

I hope this works!